# Finding the maximum percentage of people who are not in A or B

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

60% of the population is in A
50% of the population is in B

To get the maximum number of people in neither, is it right to find the maximum number of people in both (50% in this case) and plug that in to the inclusion-exclusion formula?

(A or B) = A + B - (A and B) + None

So would the max of neither be 40%?

Comment: Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to look at it:
$$\begin{align}|A\cup B|+none&=100\% \Rightarrow \\
none&=100\%-|A\cup B|=100\%-(|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|)=\\
&=100\%-60\%-50\%+|A\cap B|=\\
&=|A\cap B|-10\%.\end{align}$$
Hence, none (neither) is maximum $40\%$ when $|A\cap B|$ is maximum $50\%$.

Comment: Thanks! Just realized I had my equations wrong, posted this late at night :/

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is wrong, but your result is right. We have

$$
|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|
$$

(which corresponds to your equation without the “None” term), and since you want to minimize $|A\cup B|$ with $|A|$ and $|B|$ given, you need to maximize $|A\cap B|$.